# Remove AngularJS template requests from chrome console

Tags: angularjs, console

This seems like an easy one but i can't wrap my head around it. i am using a lot of partials in an angularjs app im working on and they crowd out the chrome console when i enable xhr logging. how can i avoid them showing up in the console?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve that via Chrome console. Open the console, select the filters, tick the regex selector checkbox and put this regex `(?!(.html".))$`.

This will basically exclude all logs that end with **.html".**

You can modify this regex based on your Chrome version. In my chrome it logs angular requests like **XHR finished loading: GET "https://example.com/a423b495/views/_users.html".**

Comment: i think that is the right path but that regex (as well as several others i tried) didn't work for me.

Comment: Let me confirm this again. Which version of chrome and OS you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Theres another way to create templates using a script tag

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="partial1.html">
  <div ng-controller="partial1Ctrl">
     html
  <div>
</script>
```

then you only access it like an html document.
so you can have your partials grouped in less files

Answer (score 0):

Select the filters and put:

```
mime-type:application/json
```

in the filter